# Java JMS clarification needed

Tags: java, jms

1 quick question, recently I came across a new concept in java called JMS. I would like to know where it exactly applies and I have a doubt that JMS is an abstraction or an implementation. If so how would I can use this? Can any body help me in understanding this. Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS in specific or messaging in general is way to decouple systems.

Let's say I have a service A that handles creating new accounts, and a service B that needs to be notified when new accounts are created.

One way to connection these systems is using JMS; when service A creates an account, it puts an appropriate message on the JMS bus. Service B is listening on the bus and can take action when it sees the message. If a new service "C" also needs to take action, it can also just listen on the bus for that message. Service "A" doesn't need to know about services B or C.

All that needs to be agreed upon by all parties is the format of the JMS message.

This is a looser form of coupling than, say, service A having to explicitly contact services B & C in some way.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your inputs. Can you tell me JMS is an abstraction or an implementation can I use as it is ???

Comment: JMS itself is just an API specification; to use it in an app you need a concrete implementation such as Tibco or ActiveMQ

Answer (score 0):

In short JMS API is Abstraction and Vendors[e.g. Sun, Apache, RedHat] comes with their implementation.
If you need to know more or for any query, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Well, to clarify Adam's answer, JMS Topic Architecture can be compared equated with Service Bus architecture but JMS Queues are FIFO Pipes, where delivery gurantee gets achieved by specifying each pair of Message Producer and Message Consumer.